# Parsehub it is not working properly for scraping data

Tags: php, json, csv, parsing, parsehub

We have configured the **Parsehub** Desktop Tool and also we got data in `csv` and `json` format.

The Parsehub Desktop Tool was working fine earlier day but now it is not working properly for scraping data, when we generate (csv and json) format its throw exception :

```
This run had an empty results file. Have you tried test running your
project? A test run will let you step through your project to find any issues. 
Check out our test run tutorial or our empty results tutorial for more help
```

Answer (score 0):

I give you link but I am not sure your problem resolve. https://help.parsehub.com/hc/en-us/articles/219544708-Empty-file-with-no-results

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens frequently.

The fixes mentioned here may not always work.
https://help.parsehub.com/hc/en-us/articles/219544708-Empty-file-with-no-results

The underlying issues could be Parsehub servers being blocked temporarily by the target website. Therefore Parsehub is not a dependable tool for long term scraping.